# Subclassing Bluebird's OperationalError

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I'm promisifying a 3rd party library that doesn't throw typed errors, but instead uses the "err" function callback to notify the caller of the error. In this case, the "error" that the library is reporting is just an anonymous JS object with a few well-defined properties.

Bluebird is wrapping this in an OperationalError, which is great - but it'd be even more handy if I could subclass OperationalError and provide my own well-defined Error type that I could define. For instance LibraryXOperationalError - in order to distinguish the errors from this library, from some other error, in some sort of global express error handling middleware.

Is this possible? I tried to come up with a solution using the "promisifier" concept, but haven't had success.

Answer (score 0):

OperationalError is subclassable just like Error is, you can get a reference from `Promise.OperationalError`

Comment: I know it's subclassable - what I'm really looking for is the hook to say:

When I Promisifiy library X, all of the errors propagated should be XOperationalError instead of OperationalErrors.

Comment: Use a custom promisifier

Comment: Yeah, that was the route I was trying to take (as mentioned above). I'll continue down that path.

Comment: That'd be significantly slower most likely though - why'd you wanna subclass it anyway that way?

Comment: I'm developing a REST API, and all of the serialization of errors into JSON is handling in a global error middleware handler.

Many of the 3rd party libraries I use don't define their own typed Errors - so my fear is that I'm just passing OperationalErrors I'll lose my ability to really distinguish the original source of the errors. Does that make sense?